# Can you simply move a router from one place to another without having to reconfigure it?

Tags: networking, router

My home wireless router (D-Link DIR655) displays some behavior that I want to test on my work computer.  Can I simply bring the router to work and plug it into my work modem and expect it to function correctly?  Or would I have to reconfigure it at work?

Also, is it possible that my work network somehow blocks people from adding their own routers?

Comment: Is the 'work modem' used only by you?  That seems unlikely.  If you're talking about unplugging your work router from your work modem to test your home router, you will affect anyone else who connects to the work router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the network of your work, it's difficult to fully answer your question, but generally routers are not just plug and play.  You'll more than likely have to configure something somewhere.  Most workplace networks have domains and DNS servers.  Your network at home, generally has the router act as your DNS server.  With that alone there will be some conflicts.

You might get lucky and plug everything in and it will work, but you also might get luck and win the lottery as well.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reconfigure it, routers are configured to settings unique to your telephone line, therefore you'll need to make sure that it matches the settings to the ones at work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply going to connect the router to your work network ethernet port in the wall (this is where you normally connect your PC at work), then yes it will work as long as dhcp is turned on in your router from home, it will be unless someone disabled it. If you are connecting to a Domain network, then there could be other issues that prevent it from working.

It won't hurt to try.